# PHP Excel 01simple-download-xlsx.php and 07reader.php giving different output

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to run 2 example of PHPExcel

01simple-download-xlsx.php and 07reader.php

01simple-download-xlsx.php Working Perfect but this example 07reader.php is showing error mentioned below Why can't understand since last 4 hours.
Any one can kindly tell me why this is happening when the file is using same directory structure.

> Warning: require_once(../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php): failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Examples\07reader.php
>   on line 37
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php'
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\Examples\07reader.php
>   on line 37

Comment: It's telling you that the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\manazeschool\software\office_admin\exam_excel\PHPExcel\IOFactory.php` does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the examples (such as the 01* files) correctly use an absolute pathname `__DIR__ . '../Classes/...'` to include the main PHPExcel library, which means you don't need to be in the /Examples directory to run them.

Other examples (07reader.php included) simply use a relative pathname `'../Classes/...'`to include the main PHPExcel library, which means you do need to be in the /Examples directory to run them.

To resolve the issue, either ensure that you're in the /Examples folder when you run these files, or modify the include to use the absolute pathname.

I believe I've now fixed all of these example files to use the absolute pathname in the development branch on github.

Comment: I am 100% confirm file is inside Example folder still giving error

Comment: Unable to replicate here against all previous versions: if I'm in the same folder as the 07Reader file, then it runs correctly (a live version wouldn't be released if a test as fundamental as 07reader.php failed to run)

Comment: Have you tried modifying the 07reader.php file to add the __DIR__ reference to the include (as has been done for all Example scripts in the source repository on github)

Comment: Thank you for considering my issue, I used header() and redirected the page to php page where I am using PHPExcel.php and PHPExcel/IOFactory.php for generating and downloading Excel file.

Comment: upto this I am successful now i try to get a value P1.php from where I am passing the value `$url = "exam_excel/P2.php?c_id=".$classes_id;
header("Location: ".$url);` and this where I am generating Excel file base on following SQL - `$classes_id = $_GET['c_id']; $SQL="SELECT `admissionnumber`,`pre_name` FROM `es_preadmission` WHERE `pre_class`='$c_id'` but download Excel file give an error "Excel cannot open the file 'new file.xlsx' because file format or file.." but if I use this code `$SQL="SELECT `admissionnumber`,`pre_name` FROM `es_preadmission` WHERE `pre_class`='1'"; it fine

Comment: Open the file in a text editor, and look to see if there are any PHP error messages displayed... or if there are any leading or trailing whitespace characters

Comment: You are awesome. I found this error in Excel file opend in notepad "<br /><b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in..."  I check the code and found that I place $cid in SQL in place of $classes.id. Thank you Sir